# How to modify area polygon in postgres?

Tags: postgis, qgis, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automated correction of parcel geometry based on area measure](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14849/automated-correction-of-parcel-geometry-based-on-area-measure)

I need a function to modify area polygon in PostgreSQL. 
The major problem is automated correction of parcel geometry based
on area measure, so I need to modify area polygon in PostgreSQL

Comment: the major probleme is automated correction of parcel geometry based  
on area measure, so i need to modify area polygone in postgres
any help is welcome 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have a column `area` which contains old data. In that case you could: remove the column and calculate the area directly when you need it, or (if your dataset is not changing anymore) you could update the area column specifically:

```
UPDATE mydata set area=ST_area(geometry) WHERE xxx;
```